# How to do left join with tables with composite key and condition?

Tags: database, left-join

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbdAq.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRTht.png)

I would like to join these table so that I need fruits with number 1 and fruits with number 12.

It should look like this:
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDtWc.png)

The problem is even if I use left join I still need a criteria that it should be 12 or nothing, but if it doesnt exist in the second table it wont show it.

Comment: update your post to add tables from here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: Then remove the images. You also need to tag the database you are using: Mysql, etc.